# Posting form data from a non-html file

Tags: php

In order to post form data to a php file,  is it necessary that the file which contains the code for the form also needs to be a .php file or it could also be a .html file?

Comment: Could be .html, too. Form code = HTML code. However, question is - what is desired behavior on form page?

Comment: It may be an .html file, for example containing a `<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="" id="">` tag.

Comment: No, just as long as there are no php directives and that it points to a php handler.

Comment: My code works well if the file in which the form is made is a .php file.   If I'm making it .html,  the other file i.e the php file which needs to recieve the data isn't able to fetch data by POST or GET method.

Answer (score 0):

The form itself can be in a .html file, however the receiving file cannot be .html and in your case sounds like it should be a .php.  If it is redirecting to itself then it must be a .php file.

You set the recieving file like so:

```
<form action="processform.php" method="POST">
```